# disable everything except my div using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

very short question.
can I using angularjs disable every thing in the screen ONCE except one div?
and if that is not possible using angularjs
what is the best way to do that in my angularjs application using other technology

Comment: One solution could be adding an `ng-disabled` attribute directive to the the other elements.

Comment: I added it from here [link]https://github.com/pleerock/angular-disable-all, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to disable everything but one div in your html it actually depends on your html structure also. For example you have a

```
<div id="upperDiv">
......
</div>
```

and your div is outside of this div like

```
<div id="yourdiv">
..
</div>
```

You can basically add ng-disabled to upper div and ng-hide upper div and show only your div in the page. Like;

```
<div id="upperDiv" ng-disabled="true" ng-hide="true">
....
</div>
```

and your div ;

```
<div id="yourDiv" ng-show="true" ng-disabled="false">
...
</div>
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: thank you but I don't want to hide it, and when I added ng-disabled="true" to the div, the compomemts on it didn't effect with this attribure

Comment: you said you want to disable all divs except one.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/pleerock/angular-disable-all and it works fine //////